# Ember view flashing on load and refresh

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am very new to Ember, and have been handed an application with various issues to solve. It is a 5(possibly more) year old project, using `Ember 1.4`.

I have two views:

- LoginPageView
- DashboardView

In the `index.html` page I have a `handlebars` script tag with an if statement, like so:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#if notLoggedIn}}
    {{view TLC.LoginPageView}}
  {{else}}
    {{view TLC.DashboardView}}
    {{outlet}}
  {{/if}}
</script>
```

When a user logins in, they are directed to the `DashboardView` but the `LoginPageView` flashes for a split second, and when the user is logged in, if they hit refresh, the `LoginPageView` flashes, making the application look untidy and a bit unprofessional.

I can't see anything wrong with the syntax, only thought could be is that the `template.js` file I am using is a large file and is taking its time to load?

***Question***

How do I prevent the `LoginPageView` from displaying on login and/or when the user refreshes the page?

If you need any more information i.e. script, html, just let me know.

```
TLC.LoginPageView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'LoginPage',
});

TLC.DashboardView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'Dashboard',
});
```

Comment: What about using [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth), it does the work for you. Too simple to use ;)

Comment: You could try [loading substate](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/). BTW, 1.4 is too old, It's going to be hard to support now.

Comment: Yeah I've come to realise this. Thank you for your advice